# Looking for a job while being new in the current position

Tags: interviewing, job-search, recruitment

A friend of mine was hired recently by a company (a couple of weeks ago). She applied to another position recently in a different company and she will have an interview soon.

We were discussing this topic yesterday and I advised her that she should have a good reason why she wants to change the company that quick. She told me that it's because of the salary, and I think this reason might make her look bad or the recruiter might think she is only looking for the salary, although it's a fact for most employees).

What do you think?
Is her excuse totally fine?

Comment: How does he/she want to explain the reason to leave so soon to the hiring manager of the new company ? Does s/he want to tell the truth: "**I am after a higher salary**." ?

Comment: @Job_September_2020, yes. Would that be fine?

Answer (score 3):

It is a major red flag.

What proof do I have that she won't start looking for greener pastures the second she lands the job? It takes time to get a new hire up to speed. It costs money to look for people, but once I have the net out, I'd rather not pull it back in until I knew I landed a keeper. I'd rather not hire someone and then have to replace them 3 months later.

Now if it she took one job to pay the bills, and is applying to work in an industry that she is passionate about, (Which also happens to pay more). That is a different story entirely (I know a lot of people who have done this, it can be hard to land your first job).

Alternatively if she took a job and then found out she was being grossly underpaid compared to the industrial average, and so started looking elsewhere. That is also a different story. I wouldn't use that as the reason I was changing jobs... Something neutral like "I want to work for a company that respects its employees." or "that provides growth opportunities"... works well.

I highly recommend that her reason for leaving not be **"I want more money"**

Answer (score 2):

If your friend tells the recruiters that the only reason she wants to change her job so soon is that she wants a higher salary, then the recruiters may not like that answer very much. The recruiter and hiring managers may think that if their company gives your friend a job, very soon she will be looking for another job with a higher salary.

It takes time and effort to train a new worker. If the new worker leaves very soon, then the company will think that they waste time and resource to train that worker and do not get much back in return.